# Clarify or can't understand what is "unclear" what you're asking?

Tags: support

What should posters do if they can't understand what is 'unclear' in 'put on hold as unclear what you're asking' or why question is 'put on hold as unclear what you're asking'? This is when the closers didn't write in the question why. It aids me to know what needs clarification ahead of editing to clarify. Thanks to all.

Is a poster sanctioned to post a question on meta every time a question is put on hold?

Comment: I've found your posts rather difficult to understand at times, and unfortunately I suspect it has to do with your use of the English language. For example you like to use the word "presage". It is not in the common vocabulary of many English speakers, and your usage is rather archaic: in modern English an object presages (i.e. gives a warning about) an event, and the original meaning of "to learn beforehand" is quite uncommon now.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is consider whether or not your question is obvious and clear. Have you muddled the explanation? Given enough context for it to make sense? Have you buried it inside other exposition? Unusual formatting makes it difficult to quickly identify the question?

Simply rewriting a post with an aim to communicate more effectively can sometimes help a lot -- yes, English skills really do help in math!

Checking your history, I have a guess as to what question you're referring to: setting your actual questions inside the blockquotes (rather than putting quoted text in blockquotes) had the effect that when I was skimming your question, my eyes were looking everywhere *except* the blockquoted text trying to find the question; I never realized questions 2 and 3 were what you were actually asking until my third pass through. Didn't even see question 1 until after that.

Comment: From [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/when-should-i-use-for-writing) it seems that using blockquote to highlight the actual question (or some other important part of post), is quite common practice at this site. (I did not have a look at the actual post by OP, I am just making a general remark. I definitely agree that using blockquotes for two purposes (both for highlighting some parts and for quoting some other text) in the same post might be confusing unless they are sufficiently separated from each other.

Comment: @Martin: I *have* seen it used to good effect and I would normally agree, if not for my actual experience of trying to skim that particular post!